# Optparse Python Set Boolean

Tags: python, boolean, optparse

I'm having a ton of trouble getting optparse to work in python.  It is my first time using it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I read through all the documentation, but even with their examples, it is not working for me.  I am trying to use --clean to make a boolean variable equal to true.  This is what I have:

```
desc = "Use this script for fun!"
parser = optparse.OptionParser(description=desc)
parser.add_option('--clean', help='Run cleaner option', dest = 'runclean', default = False, action = 'store_true')
(args, opts) = parser.parse_args()

print opts.runclean
```

I thought this would set runclean to true, but when I do:

```
print opts.runclean
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list object has no attribute 'runclean'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: **Note**: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the return values reversed:

```
(args, opts) = parser.parse_args()
```

**should be**

```
(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Everything will then work.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!  I can't believe I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

It is in args.runclean

BTW, it is better to use argparse rather than optparse